# Why is twitter unreachable from Chrome but not Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, dns, twitter

I am using macOS 10.13.6. When I go to www.twitter.com in Google Chrome I get a

```
This site can't be reached.
https://www.twitter.com/ is unreachable.
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

On the same machine I can fire up Safari and I can get to the same url with no problem. On Chrome I tried using a guest and incognito account with no luck. I also used the settings feature to restore settings to their original default. Nothing seems to help. I am not having this problem with any other site, just twitter.

Comment: What proxies are set up for Safari? ie what does System Preferences->Network - hit Advanced button and use Proxies tab

Comment: That tab has under **Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:** `*.local, 169.254/16`

Comment: What if any protocols have ben set?

Comment: None of the checkboxes above are enabled and I don't see anything specific about Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Egad. I run a network filter (which I thought I disabled when testing this problem) but it turns out I had a rule to deny outgoing connections to twitter.com, which maybe, just maybe, was causing the problem. Mark - thanks for the help and sorry for wasting the bandwidth.